# Android 12 prerequisites for launcing app from bixby key?

Tags: android, android-studio, bixby

I made an app a while back that has no activity, it just runs some code such as setting phone to mute / unmting when i try to open the app. On my S8+ i could remap the bixby key to single press open that app and it worked just fine. Recently i got my hands on an S10+ for developping, running android 12 and the bixby key single press refuses to launch that app but it will launch any other app. I did confirm that launcing the app manually does still work as intended, just nost through the bixby key.

So my question is if they have changed some prerequisites that must be set in the manifest or so before it will launch it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that android 12 required each activity to have the "exported" tag set in the manifest. I set those to false because i didnt know what it meant at first, but changing it to true has made the bixby key able to launch my app again